# hosting site on one web server and accessing a database on another

Tags: database, web-hosting, 1and1

I'm fairly sure this is the right place for this question, but if not please move it to the the right site.

I have a number of sites on a 1and1 package (yeah, I know...) and I also have a subdomian that belongs to a college tutor. I have been playing around with PHP and MySQL databases on the subdomian site and would like to know if it is possible to run a database driven (i.e. blog) on one of my 1and1 sites. I *could* upgrade my package but if I'm only going to gain database functionality I'm not sure if I want to do it.

Also, I'm wondering how the databases would be managed...but I'll worry about that when (if) the time comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking if you can host a MySQL database on your college tutor's sub-domain and then use that database from a remote shared hosting account at 1on1?  Possibly, but I wouldn't recommend it -- the latency would be brutal querying over the Internet.  Also, it's doubtful that your college tutor's host allows MySQL to listen on an external interface.

Having said that, hosting is dirt cheap: you should be able to get a $5/month account with at least a few MySQL databases.

Comment: the tutors site won't accept requets from a seprate site so I've taken the plunge and got a upgrade. Bit more server space and two databases to play with, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Check out dreamhost.com or hostgator.com too.  Decent shared hosting plans there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is.. you can manage your mysql database with phpmyadmin, you don't need cpanel for that even if you're on a shared host.